# Problem with loading additional ttf fonts, specifically mfizz

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontspec

I am using the Kile IDE, compiling with PdfLatex. I am not using fontspec because it seems to be overly complicated for what I have been doing; I tried switching to fontspec, with many variations, and could not even get the main font I chose to work!

The preamble below works without mfizz, but I cannot figure out how to also add font-mfizz.ttf (the full name of the file in my fonts folder; see http://fizzed.com/oss/font-mfizz). I keep getting an error message, <***font-mfizz.sty not found***>
The iwona font is Iwona-Regular.ttf and I am ***not*** getting the same error message with that ttf.

BTW, I found an older "answer" to an inquiry about *.sty not being found for a ttf font, but when I tried to implement that TeX.Stackexchange answer, it did not work
Here is my preamble with the offending mfizz commented-out:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
%\usepackage{font-mfizz}
\usepackage{todo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hycolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,backref]{hyperref}

\renewcommand*\rmdefault{iwona}
\usepackage[includehead=false,bottom=1in,top=1in,inner=.8in,outer=1.5in, heightrounded, marginparsep=4mm, marginparwidth=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen, bookmarks=true, bookmarksopen=true,linkcolor=ForestGreen, pdfhighlight =/O urlcolor=BlueViolet, anchorcolor=Maroon}


\begin{document}
some text with a mfizz item \mfElixir
\end{document}
```

---

Thanks for every comment.
I continued to work (hack at) this using fontspec. Trolling through tex.stackexchange, I found bits of preamble to try and this ended up working---using **LuaLatex** compiler:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage{amssym}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontmfizz}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{todo}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hycolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,backref]{hyperref}
\usepackage[includehead=false,bottom=1in,top=1in,inner=.8in,outer=1.5in, heightrounded, marginparsep=4mm, marginparwidth=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\PassOptionsToPackage{protrusion=true,final}{microtype}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Ligatures=TeX]{iwona}

%\ExplSyntaxOn
%\SetSymbolFont{operators}{iwona}\g_fontspec_encoding_tl\g__fontspec_mathrm_tl\mddefault\updefault
%\SetSymbolFont{operators}{iwonabold}\g_fontspec_encoding_tl\g__fontspec_mathrm_tl\bfdefault\updefault
%\ExplSyntaxOff

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen, bookmarks=true, bookmarksopen=true,linkcolor=ForestGreen, pdfhighlight =/I urlcolor=BlueViolet, anchorcolor=Maroon}

\begin{document}
some math here \mfElixir\ \ \faBomb
        \begin{equation}
            x^2+3x+4y
        \end{equation}\\

it works!
\end {document}
```

Note the commented-out lines in the preamble...by trial and error it seems that these are not presently needed in my document. Where can I find the best explanation of the **\ExplSyntaxOn** (& Off) and **\SetSymbolFont** commands? I find myself swimming in the deep end, and would like to grasp what effect these lines might have on a document with more complex math entries!

Also, the package **polyglossia** cannot, in the case of this preamble, be removed  without creating a compilation error. In this preamble, what other packages and commands are dependent upon **polyglossia**?

Comment: you can not simply use a ttf font with pdflatex, you would need to choose a 256 character subset and generate tfm metric files and map files that tex can read. It is _much_ easier to use lualatex and simply load the ttf file by name using `fontspec`

Comment: in the case of iwona someone prepared it for use with pdftex and generated all the needed files (including a .sty). For other ttf you will have to do that yourself. See e.g. https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94thanh.pdf, the fontinstallationguide and the autoinst documentation.  As David wrote: lualatex is much easier.

Comment: or as this is an icon font just make images of the ones you need and include with `\includegraphics`

Comment: I just checked `find  /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist -type f -name \*iwona\* | wc -l`  reports there are 723 files setting up iwona in texlive 2022.